# Como insertar un campo duplicado

Tags: javascript

Estoy haciendo un Js que me permita crear un nuevo elemento(div) y que este dentro me crea un datalist, pero cuando creo uno nuevo me lo duplica bien, pero el datalist que es para añadir más campos se me duplica en el div principal.

Este es todo mi Javascript

```js
var i = 0;
function duplicate(){
    i++
    let campos = document.createElement('div');
    id_definitiva = campos.id = 'ecopy' + i;
    campos.innerHTML = `
    <br>
    <div class="form-duplicate" id="ecopy" ><div class="formulario-principal" id="formulario-dividido">
    <div class="inputs">
        <input class="input_form" type="text" placeholder="Nombre Completo">
        <input class="input_form" type="text" placeholder="Identificacion">
        <input class="input_form" type="text" placeholder=" Telefono">
    </div>
    <button onclick="duplicate()" class="btn btn-duplicate" type="button" id="btn-duplicate" name="btn-duplicate">Agregar nuevo paciente</button>    
</div>
    <br>
        <div class="country" id="country">
            <h4 class="title-autocomplete">Exámenes:</h4>
        <input type="text" id="states" name="states" list="states-list">
        <button onclick="duplicate_country()" class="btn btn-duplcate_exam" type="button" id="button_examn" name="btn-duplicate-country">+</button>
        <datalist id="states-list">
        <option>México</option>
        <option>Estados Unidos</option>
        </datalist>
        </div>
<br>`;
document.getElementById('duplicates').appendChild(campos);
}

var j = 0
function duplicate_states() {
    j++
    let examenes = document.createElement('div');
    id_examenes = examenes.id = 'states' + j;
    examenes.innerHTML = `
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="states" name="states" list="states-list">
     <button onclick="duplicate_country()" class="btn btn-duplcate_exam" type="button" id="button_examn" name="btn-duplicate-state">+</button>
    <datalist id="states-list">
    <option>New York</option>
    <option>Manhattan</option>
    <option>Ciudad de México</option>
    </datalist>
    <br>
    `;
    document.getElementById('examenes').appendChild(states);
}
```

Lo que no me quiere funcionar es como hacer para que los nuevos div que creo me inserte los datalist en el nuevo div que se creo no el original. Espero haber sido claro

Comment: No, no eres claro, lo siento. Pon el HTML que ejecuta ese javascript para que podamos entenderte mejor. Léete [example] para acotar tu problema y verlo insitu. En mis pruebas aparentemente funciona bien, es decir, se crea un datalist para cada elemento que se crea, aunque todos tienen el mismo nombre, y aunque al inventarme el HTML no creo que haya podido reproducir tu error. Léete tambien [ask] y [tour] para aprender a formular mejores preguntas y como funciona este sitio.